# Rating system on laravel issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm a complete newbie to laravel looking for a fix.
I bought a script and I wanted to customise a review page and increase the number of ratings with stars from 1 row to 3 rows of questions.

```
        <div class='give-rating'>
            @for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--)
                <span>
                    <input id='str{{ $i }}' name='rating' type='radio'
                        value='{{ $i }}'>
                    <label for='str{{ $i }}'><i class="las la-star fa-sm"></i></label>
                </span>
            @endfor
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- start of my bullshit -->
        <div class="give-rating-person2">
        <!-- <div class="thumb">
        <img src="{{ getImage(imagePath()['profile']['user']['path'] . '/' . auth()->user()->image, null, true) }}"  alt="image">
        </div>-->
        <div class="content">
            <h6>Timelyness</h6>
        </div>
    
        <div class='give-rating'>
            @for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--)
                <span>
                    <input id='str{{ $i }}' name='rating' type='radio'
                        value='{{ $i }}'>
                    <label for='str{{ $i }}'><i class="las la-star fa-sm"></i></label>
                </span>
            @endfor
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of my bullshit -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <textarea name="review" class="form--control" placeholder="@lang('Write review')" required>{{ old('review') }}</textarea>
            <div class="text-end">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn--base">@lang('Submit')</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

here's what I have so far. The frontend seems okay but the review stars for all the rows all behave as one. I tried changing the id but it breaks the page.
Any advice?

Comment: I can't even tell if this is a PHP question or a HTML/CSS question, tbh. And what does _"breaks the page"_ actually mean? Is it all white? Do you see any errors? Is it some function that doesn't work? Is there some JS that causes issues when you change the id's? Have you checked the console for errors? Does the computer explode? Please be _specific_.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)